# How to find records with multiple column values matching user input?

Tags: sql, sql-like

I have a table which contains patients information in it.

```
First_Name    Last_Name 
TEST          DO NOT USE
LEES          ESTATE
LEES          ROSA
```

So, based on user input I need to search if First_Name or Last_Name matches with user input. If user entered multiple words, I should split the word and check each word against First_Name and Last_Name columns.

For example, if user input is "D N U", I need to get first row.

If user input is "ES" I need get all three rows. Similarly , If user input is "SA ES" I need get third rows.

I'm trying to use LIKE Operator, but I think there should be more logic applied to achieve what I require.

Comment: This is not a small program. Did you try it before?

Comment: I'm trying to do this through application instead of doing it in a stored procedure. But wanted to know if this can be done in SQL or not.

Comment: In one word, YES, It's possible.

Comment: What did you try? What was wrong with the results of your own attempt?

Comment: I'm trying to split the word in application and for each word I'm connecting to DB and checking it using LIKE on First and Last Name and saving result in a table in my application. But I wanted to try it in SQL in which I don't have much knowledge on so wanted help.

Comment: I suggest you first try to split your input string using recursive query using the `WITH` keyword.  You can then use a `JOIN` against that result to build your result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that something like this would work:

```
where concat(last_name, ' ', first_name) like concat('%', replace($user_input, ' ', '%'), '%')
```

The exact method for string concatenation varies by database.